# Solve for $x$: $\frac{60x - 20}{16} = 4x - 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve for $x$:

$$ \displaystyle \frac{60x - 20}{16} = 4x - 2$$

Then what must $x$ equal?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It helps to format questions using MathJax (see FAQ). If this is HW, it should be tagged as such. It helps to share your thoughts and what you have tried so we may provide better guidance. Regards

Answer (score 1):

If I'm correctly interpreting you, you want to solve $$\frac{60x-20}{16}=4x-2.$$ Note that the numerator and denominator on the left have $4$ as a common factor, so dividing both numerator and denominator by $4$ gives us the equivalent $$\frac{15x-5}4=4x-2.$$ At this point, I recommend multiplying both sides by $4$ and solving.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \frac{60x - 20}{16} = 4x - 2 \\ $$

$$ \color{blue}{16} \cdot \frac{60x - 20}{16} = \color{blue}{16} \cdot (4x - 2) $$
$$ 60x - 20 = 16(4x - 2) $$
$$ 60x - 20 = 16 \cdot 4x - 16 \cdot 2 $$
$$ 60x - 20 = 64x - 32 $$
$$ 60x - 20 - \color{green}{60x} = 64x - 32 - \color{green}{60x} $$
$$ - 20 = 4x - 32  $$
$$ - 20 + \color{orange}{32}  = 4x - 32 + \color{orange}{32} $$
$$ 12 = 4x $$
$$ \frac{12}{\color{blue}{4}} = \frac{4x}{\color{blue}{4}} $$
$$ 3 = x $$

Alternatively:

$$ \frac{60x - 20}{16} = 4x - 2 \\ $$
$$ \frac{4(15x - 5)}{16} = 4x - 2 $$
$$ \frac{15x - 5}{4} = 4x - 2 $$
$$ \color{blue}{4} \cdot \frac{15x - 5}{4} = \color{blue}{4}(4x - 2) $$
$$ 15x - 5 = 16x - 8 $$
$$ 15x - 5 - \color{green}{15x} = 16x - 8 - \color{green}{15x} $$
$$ -5 = x - 8 $$
$$ -5 + \color{orange}{8} = x - 8 + \color{orange}{8} $$
$$ 3 = x - 8 + 8 $$
$$ 3 = x  $$